# why won't an XP VM connect to the Internet, when it says its connected to a WiFi network?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I have this windows XP virtual machine. I want to connect it to my WiFi network, but when I do it gives me an error saying the website wasn't found. I'm trying to do this so I can have a WinXP VM to hack from my Kali VM. I need to be able to connect to properly install certain programs and run them properly.

Comment: In the title you say that you are connected to the WiFi network whereas in the topic you say that it gives an error trying to connect to the WiFi. A bit unclear ...

Comment: Use "ipconfig /all" to find out if the VM get correct IP address and default gateway from the Wifi network.

Comment: When I restarted XP, with the driver installed, it let me connect.